# GUI Programming in LISP?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I did a fair amount of Lisp programming a few years back, but it was all really console-based things. I did use `cells-gtk`(2), but now that's really not maintained anymore and obviously we're Gtk3 now.

Does anyone know of a good Lisp library for GUI programming (I don't mind if which dialect).

Comment: 2020: an overview of solutions for Common Lisp include Tk, Qt4, Gtk3, IUP, Nuklear (and Electron): https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/gui.html

Answer (score 12):

For Common Lisp all the solutions are listed in [Cliki](http://www.cliki.net/GUI) as usual.

Personally I am quite content with [ltk](http://www.cliki.net/ltk), but it's probably not for complex GUIs. [CAPI](http://www.lispworks.com/products/capi.html) should be the best for such.

Answer (score 4):

If you are into scheme check out [chicken](http://wiki.call-cc.org/)  which gets compiled to C and has very good Foreign Function Interface support to call native C code. If you go down that path , a lot of options arise.

- interfacing libGTK using FFI ([easyffi example](http://wiki.call-cc.org/An%20extended%20FFI%20example))
- using the [SDL egg](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/g2)
- using the [XLIB egg](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/xlib)
- using the [cairo egg](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/cairo)

good luck!

Answer (score 3):

If you really mean that you don't mind the dialect, then you can have a look at [Racket which has GUI toolkit](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/).

Answer (score 3):

You could also consider ABCL, which is a Common Lisp that runs in the jdk, and has interfaces for calling out to Java classes.  The ABCL website has one or two simple examples of Lisp programs that use Java libraries for graphics.

Answer (score 2):

Clozure Common Lisp and OS X Cocoa through CCL's Objective C bridge.

Answer (score 1):

For common lisp you can try the LTK library, which is a wrapper for TCL/TK. Works on linuxes and on windows(on windows with the Active State distribution of tcl/tk).